# Longest Non Repeating Substring in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, substring

I am trying to find the longest substring with no repeated characters.
I have a boolean vector to keep track of the 256 ascii characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "aaaaaaaaaaaaasadfrhtytbgrbrsvsrhvsg";
    vector<bool> v(256, false);
    int j = 0, len = 0, index = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if(!v[s[i]])
        {
            j++;

            if(j > len)
            { 
                len = j;
                index = i - j;
            }

            v[s[i]] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            j = 0;
            v.clear();
        }
    }

    cout << s.substr(index, len) + " " << len << endl;
}
```

I can understand why it gives the output `adfrht 6` , whreas the correct output is sadfrhty 8.

Comment: You mean you can't or can understand?

Comment: Do you have any time complexity limit? or you just want the answer no matter how long it takes to execute.

Comment: @Ediac the algo seems to be correct.

Comment: @Rasoolll O(n) is the best we can achieve i think.

Comment: @adrian008 shouldn't the correct output be `sadfrhty 8` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you're getting the wrong result is because the basic approach is missing a few moving pieces. You're not tracking all the information that you need to calculate this. Not only you need to track which characters you have seen, but also at which position in the string they were seen at (I presume that you wish to keep this at O(n) complexity).

This way, when you see a character that's been encountered before, you need to reset the "consecutive non-repeated characters seen so far" counter to begin *after* the previous occurrence of the same character that you're looking at, in the current position. Additionally, all the characters that were seen so far, until that point, are no longer seen, because if you think about it for a second, it should make sense to you.

That's the missing piece from your implementation. Also, it's not tracking the position of the longest string, quite right.

The following should produce the results you were looking for.

Let us know what grade you received for your homework assignment :-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "aaaaaaaaaaaaasadfrhtytbgrbrsvsrhvsg";
    vector<bool> v(256,false);
    vector<int> seen_at(256);

    int longest_starting_pos=0, longest_length=0;

    int current_length=0;

    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (v[s[i]])
        {
            for (int j=i-current_length; j<seen_at[s[i]]; ++j)
                v[s[j]]=false;
            current_length=i-seen_at[s[i]]-1;
        }

        v[s[i]]=true;
        seen_at[s[i]]=i;
        if (++current_length > longest_length)
        {
            longest_length=current_length;
            longest_starting_pos=i-current_length+1;
        }
    }

    cout<<s.substr(longest_starting_pos, longest_length)+" "<<longest_length<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is not correct. What is wrong with your algorithm is that once it checks a character, it does not go back to that character to check it again if the substring including that character fails to be the longest. The first `s` is being checked in the string of length 2 which is `as`, but when the next `a` is found, the `s` is forgotten, even though it could make the next substring longer. Try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "aaaaaaaaaaaaasadfrhtytbgrbrsvsrhvsg";
    vector<bool> v(256,false);
    int longStart = 0;
    int longEnd = 0;
    int start = 0

    for (end = 0; end < s.length(); end++)
    {
        if (!v[s[end]])   // if character not already in the substring
        {
            v[s[end]] = true;

            if (end - start > longEnd - longStart)
            {
                longEnd = end;
                longStart = start;
            }
        }
        else   //the character is already in the substring, so increment the
               //start of the substring until that character is no longer in it
        {
            //get to the conflicting character, but don't get to the new character
            while ((s[start] != s[end]) && (start < end))
            {
                start++;
                v[s[start]] = false;
            }

            //remove the conflicting character
            start++;
            //don't set v[s[start]] to false because that character is still
            //encountered, but as the newly appended character, not the first
        }
    }

    longEnd++;    //make longEnd the index after the last character for substring purposes
    cout << s.substr(longStart, longEnd - longStart) + " " << (longEnd - longStart) << endl;
}
```

Basically what this code does is it keeps a running substring, and whenever it encounters a character that is already in the substring, it increments the start of the substring until that new character is no longer in the substring, then continues as normal. It also checks every time the end is incremented if that substring is longer than the previously believed longest one. This is O(n) I believe as you wanted.

Also, spread your code out. Concise code means nothing if you cannot read it and debug it easily. Also, if you are having issues with your code, work it all out by hand to get a greater understanding of how it all works and what is happening.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem with your solution is that it raises the complexity from O(n) to O(n^2)

Comment: @ Sam Varshavchik No it does not. By keeping a running substring, it maintains O(n). This is essentially the same algorithm as finding the largest subsequence sum in a sequence of numbers, and that algorithm is O(n). You can see it [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/)

Comment: Your outer loop complexity's is O(n). Your inner loop's complexity is also O(n). You have an O(n)-complex loop inside another O(n)-complex loop. How is that not O(n^2)?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Also, if you think about it, the most operations that can be done are incrementing end all the way through the string (n operations), then incrementing start all the way through the string (n operation). Together they yield 2n, which reduces to O(n).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The inner loop is halted by the value of end. Meaning that start can never be greater than end. Since start only increases, start can only encounter every index in the substring once throughout the entire program, yielding n operations. Also, the inner loop can be thought of as able to be paused. When the outer loop does another iteration, the inner loop "picks back up from where it started", because start does not change outside of the inner loop. This makes the inner loop treated as a separate outer loop for O() purposes.

Comment: The algorithms you reference on code blocks are not "essentially the same". They do not employ two O(n) nested loops. The average number of iterations in the inner loop is proportional to the original string's length, and the inner loop's invocation is also proportional to the original string's length. That makes the whole thing O(n^2). Sorry.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If you still don't believe me, you can try it out with massive text inputs. Give it 1MB, 2MB, 3MB, and 4MB of text and see how long it takes to run. Should be linear.